# Counting the number of combinations of pairs for two sets with the same number of elements.

Tags: combinatorics

> I have two rows, on the first row, I have $A = \{1,2,3, \ldots, n\}$ and on the second row $B = \{n+1, n+2, \ldots, 2n\}$. What is the number of combinations of pairs that can be obtained with an element from every set?

For example if $A = \{1,2\}$ and $B = \{3,4\}$, then we have: $(1,3),(2,4)$ - first combination; $(1,4),(2,3)$ - the second combination. That mean for $n=2$ we have $2$ combinations.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** You are really just trying to count the number of bijective functions $f\colon A \to B$, where $|A| = |B| = n$. The contents of each set aren't really important; you could pretend that $A = B$ so that you would be merely counting permutations.

Comment: Tk for your response, but I'm not sure if it is OK. For example for n=3, we have the following combinations: (1,4), (2,5), (3,6) - a combination; (1,4), (2,6), (3,5) - another comb; (1,4), (3,6),(2,5) - comb; (1,4), (3,5), (2,6) - comb.; (1,5),(2,4),(3,6) comb ..etc

Comment: For $n = 3$, there are exactly $6$ combinations:
$$
(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6) \\
(1, 4), (2, 6), (3, 5) \\
(1, 5), (2, 4), (3, 6) \\
(1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 4) \\
(1, 6), (2, 4), (3, 5) \\
(1, 6), (2, 5), (3, 4)
$$

Comment: OK. In my case will be: 2n! because for n = 3 we also will have: (1,4),(3,6), (2,5);   (1,4),(3,5),(2,6);  (1,5),(3,6),(2,4); (1,5),(3,4),(2,6);  (1,6),(3,5),(2,4);  (1,6),(3,4),(2,5).